# Colocar descolar ou mover um frame no Tkinter(python)?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou com um problema no código em python que é o seguinte, tipo eu quero afastar o frame dos checkbutton do entry so que eu não consigo, se puderem me ajudar, executem o codigo ai para voces entenderem o problema.

`from Tkinter import *
from sqlite3 import *

class criar(object):
    def **init**(self, principal):

## frames e empacotamento de frames

```
    self.font = ('Arial', '18', 'bold')
    self.frame1 = Frame(principal)
    self.frame1.place()
    self.frame1.pack()
    self.frame1['bg'] = '#B5B5B5'
    self.frame2 = Frame(principal)
    self.frame2.place()
    self.frame2.pack()
    self.frame2['bg'] = '#B5B5B5'
```

## texto exibido na tela

```
    L1 = Label(self.frame1, font = self.font, text = "  Nome do Seu Banco de Dado  ", bg = '#B5B5B5')

    L1.pack()
    E1 = Entry(self.frame1, bd = 5, highlightcolor = '#1E90FF')

    E1.pack()
```

## checkButtons

```
    self.nome = Checkbutton(self.frame2, bd = 5, text = 'Nome', variable = Vnome)
    self.nome.place()
    self.nome.pack(side = LEFT)
    Vnome.get()
    self.cor = Checkbutton(self.frame2, bd = 5, text = 'Cor', variable = Vcor)
    self.cor.pack(side = LEFT)
    Vcor.get()
    self.cpf = Checkbutton(self.frame2, bd = 5, text = 'CPF', variable = Vcpf)
    self.cpf.pack(side = LEFT)
    Vcpf.get()
    self.email = Checkbutton(self.frame2, bd = 5, text = 'Email', variable = Vemail)
    self.email.pack(side = LEFT)
    Vemail.get()
```

principal = Tk()

## variaveis dos metodos dos checkButtons

Vnome = IntVar()
Vcor = IntVar()
Vcpf = IntVar()
Vemail = IntVar()

## cria a instancia

criar(principal)
principal['bg'] = '#B5B5B5'
fundo = PhotoImage('Blue')
principal.geometry('400x300')
principal.title("Gerenciador de Cadastro")
principal.mainloop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Entre** `self.frame1['bg'] = '#B5B5B5'` **e** `self.frame2 = Frame(principal)`

**coloque isto:**

```
self.frame3 = Frame(principal) # Crio um terceiro frame que ficará entre o 1 e o 2
self.frame3.pack()

Label(self.frame3).pack() # Crio um Label vazio, só para afastar
```

ficando assim:

```
    self.font = ('Arial', '18', 'bold')
    self.frame1 = Frame(principal)
    self.frame1.place()
    self.frame1.pack()
    self.frame1['bg'] = '#B5B5B5'

    self.frame3 = Frame(principal) # Crio um terceiro frame que ficará entre o 1 e o 2
    self.frame3.pack()

    Label(self.frame3).pack() # Crio um Label vazio, só para afastar

    self.frame2 = Frame(principal)
    self.frame2.place()
    self.frame2.pack()
    self.frame2['bg'] = '#B5B5B5'
```

**Resultado:**

[image: Resultado final]